# .xml cannot be opened because it does not exist but it does exists in the same package

Tags: java, xml, spring

I was writing my first code in spring.the applicationContext.xml is present in the same package where HelloSpringApp class is present.But still I am getting error as .XML file does not exists
public class HelloSpringApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //load spring config file
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml"); //error here
    
    Coach theCoach=context.getBean("myCoach",Coach.class);
    
    System.out.print(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    
    context.close();
}
```

}

error:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Comment: It tries to find it at the root, not the same package. Also if this is structured as a maven project the XML file needs to be in `src/main/resources` and not in `src/main/java`.

Comment: Sorry.can you please elaborate

Comment: elaborate on what?

Comment: ohh okay I got it now.Thank you so much!